# Aggregation data from many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-tables

Given I have 3 tables in DB, which contain different slices of data from same origin. 
All tables have pretty similar structure:

```
id | parent_id | timestamp | contents
```

Each table has parent_id (one parent to many records relationship) and timestamp index.

I need to access this data sorted on time basis. Currently I use next query:

```
prepare query3(bigint) as 
select id, timestamp, contents, filter from 
 (select t1.id, t1.timestamp, t1.contents, 'filter1' as filter from table1 t1 
where t1.parent_id = $1
  union select t2.id, t2.timestamp, t2.contents, 'filter2' as filter from table2 t2 
where t2.parent_id = $1
  union select t3.id, t3.timestamp, t3.contents, 'filter3' as filter from table3 t3 
where t3.parent_id = $1 
) table_alias order by timestamp;
```

Since there are pretty much data in each table, it takes from 2 to 3 minutes each time I execute this query. According to explain: 650000 rows and `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186592kB`.

Is there any way to optimize a retrieval execution time without changing the schema, but building more effective query or creating a specific indexes?

Update added full explain analyze result here. In this case there are 4 tables in query, but I believe there is not much difference between 3 and 4 in this case.

```
"Sort  (cost=83569.28..83959.92 rows=156258 width=80) (actual time=2288.871..2442.318 rows=639225 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: t1.timestamp"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186592kB"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=52685.43..54638.65 rows=156258 width=154) (actual time=1572.274..1885.966 rows=639225 loops=1)"
"    ->  Sort  (cost=52685.43..53076.07 rows=156258 width=154) (actual time=1572.273..1737.041 rows=639225 loops=1)"
"    Sort Key: t1.id, t1.timestamp, t1.contents, ('table1'::text)"
"    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186624kB"
"      ->  Append  (cost=0.00..14635.39 rows=156258 width=154) (actual time=0.070..447.375 rows=639225 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using table1_parent_id on table1 t1  (cost=0.00..285.08 rows=5668 width=109) (actual time=0.068..5.993 rows=9385 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (parent_id = $1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using table2_parent_id on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..11249.13 rows=132927 width=168) (actual time=0.063..306.567 rows=589056 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (parent_id = $1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using table3_parent_id on table3 t3  (cost=0.00..957.18 rows=4693 width=40) (actual time=25.234..82.381 rows=20176 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (parent_id = $1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using table4_parent_id_idx on table4 t4  (cost=0.00..581.42 rows=12970 width=76) (actual time=0.029..5.894 rows=20608 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (parent_id = $1)"
"Total runtime: 2489.569 ms"
```

Comment: have you tried putting all of that in a temp table first?

Comment: @radashk There are index for parent_id for all tables

Comment: Why not just join them all to the parent table?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I haven't tried. I believe this will save a time on frequent access to data, but since in most cases this data is requested only for couple of last days, I don't think I'll get much improvement with temp table.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin:  Boo! hiss!  temp tables bad!  especially in this situation.

Comment: @Limey Data nature. Parent table data is requested daily over 100 times, table1 data requested 10 times, table2 and so on are more populated, but required only in certain conditions.
Currently parent table1 data select is acceptably fast, but when I need merge table1 with something :(

Comment: @Vestel:  huh? you are doing a union all, and pulling from all 3 tables, if you join them in this query, it will be treated as one query, not 3.  it doesn't matter how many times a table is quered per day, the join matters to THIS query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14302/discussion-between-vestel-and-limey)

Comment: @Vestel:  would love to, but I have a meeting in mere minutes.  I'll check in later.

Comment: You can use UNION ALL. It will faster by the article: [Link](http://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/08/06/the-effects-union-in-a-sql-query/) p.s.: I love you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big chunk of your time is caused by eliminating duplicates for the union.  Use union all instead:

```
select id, timestamp, contents, filter
from  ((select t1.id, t1.timestamp, t1.contents, 'filter1' as filter
        from table1 t1 
        where t1.parent_id = $1
       )
       union all
       (select t2.id, t2.timestamp, t2.contents, 'filter2' as filter
        from table2 t2 
        where t2.parent_id = $1
       )
       union all
       (select t3.id, t3.timestamp, t3.contents, 'filter3' as filter
        from table3 t3 
        where t3.parent_id = $1 
       )
      ) table_alias
order by timestamp;
```

To make this more effective, you should have an index on parent_id on each of the three tables.  With those changes, it should run quite faste.

Comment: OK. Converting query as you purposed:

Comment: OK. Converting query as you purposed:
Inital query first run: 60 seconds, next calls 10-11 seconds.
Updated query first run: 9 seconds, next calls 9-11 seconds.